# Kies just doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, android, kies

When I run `Kies` and connect my Samsung Galaxy Tab 1 to my PC with USB cable, then connect animation starts and nothing more happens. Built-in troubleshooter reinstalls some driver, but this does not help.

What can be done?

**UPDATE**

Connecting with "Connect to Kies Via WiFi" gives the same result. First, desktop computer name is displayed on a tablet, then, if selected, desktop computer displays confirmation dialog. Then, if confirmed, animation "Connecting..." starts and nothing happens.

Using both "lite" and normal kies programs gives the same result.

Comment: I completely gave up on Kies. It is an abysmal piece of software which has no actual purpose for existing. What are you trying to make it do?

Comment: Upgrade firmware

Comment: Shouldn't firmware updates usually be pushed OTA? Regardless, I had a lot more luck with Odin when I was trying to flash stuff onto my phone, but after that I recommend setting up a custom recovery like TWRP or ClockworkMod so you can do this stuff entirely on the device, if you're planning to flash things often.

Comment: You might want to have a look at the many questions at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-kies

Answer (score 3):

Kies never worked in Windows, it always had problems. Try some more times, or reinstall that sometime will work.

If you want to continue using, you better get used to the problems.

Comment: What do you want to say? If Kies does not work under windows, then under what it does? Under Mac, i.e. Apple's operating system!?

Comment: I don't know under Mac, but under Windows I give up Kies!